# Build a docker image from Azure Pipeline Task

Tags: docker, azure-devops

In the folliwing documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops

it is mentioned that  - "Be sure your pipelines agent has permission to access the Docker daemon." How to check it, configure it and provide the permission if necessary

I get the following error while building a docker image on a VM machine with docker installed on it:

```
open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

Already checked that the docker daemon is running with the following command:

```
docker --version
```

And I can see the docker version

```
Docker version 19.03.5, build 2ee0c57608
```

Answer (score 3):

Verify that services using System account. The service is created when configuring the agent

[Screen for the configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stIwQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

> It is mentioned that - "Be sure your pipelines agent has permission to
>   access the Docker daemon." How to check it, configure it and provide
>   the permission if necessary.

It's **the user which run the agent**. You need to make sure that user have enough permission. Or you could switch your agent to run as the same user which docker daemon is running as.

More details about the error you could also kindly refer this similar issue: [container jobs fails to connect to docker daemon on Windows Server 2019](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2082)

Comment: Checked the System Capabilities under project settings in azure and it shows that the agent has the path configured to "C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe". This very same agent can access MSbuild, but not docker.

Comment: @sajis997 Sorry not totally get your point, are you using self-host agent or host agent to run your container jobs in Azure DevOps Service or Server 2019? Container Jobs are only support with yaml pipeline in Azure DevOps Service or Azure DevOps Server 2019. And if you are using host agent, The windows-2019 and ubuntu-16.04 pools support running containers. Other agents such as the Hosted macOS pool does not support running containers.

Comment: Hi @sajis997 How about the issue, is there anything to update?

Comment: Please check here : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/903169/how-to-make-sure-that-the-pipeline-agent-has-acces.html

Comment: Hi sajis997, thanks for your kindly response. Looks like this ticket in DC has been forwarded to PG team. Since it across team, there might be some time delay. Appreciate your patience.